# Vetor iniciar com elemento maior que 0 (zero)?

Tags: c#, .net, array

Normalmente um `vetor` se inicia do elemento `0`, e assim por diante até chegar no tamanho do qual foi declarado ou atribuído, exemplo:

```
string[] v = {1, 2 , 3};
// equivalente á:
v[0] = 1;
v[1] = 2;
v[2] = 3;
```

Quero saber como faço no `C#` para dar início ao vetor já em um elemento pré definido, ou seja, ao invés de começar com `v[0]` começar em `v[10]` assim:

```
v[10] = 1;
v[11] = 2;
v[12] = 3;
```

Comment: Quer que todos os valores do vetor (array) iniciem com um valor padrão, isso?

Comment: Ou que o primeiro índice seja 10? Por favor, coloque um exemplo do código que você quer que seja possível escrever...

Comment: @jbueno não todos, apenas um vetor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Em C# só vejo uma forma, criar uma estrutura própria que faça isso por você. Não poderá usar nada que já exista diretamente, *array*, `List`, nada. Tudo começa do zero. Pode ser que tenha alguma estrutura pronta que funcione de forma diferente, mas não lembro de nada padrão e duvido que tenha no .NET.

Exemplo simplificado do que pode ter em seu próprio tipo:

```
public class MyList<T> : List<T> {
    public T this[int index] {
        get => base[index - 10];
        set => base[index - 10] = value;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/BaseNonZero.cs).

Achei uma [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56495/221800) com uma implementação mais completinha por um lado, mais limitada por outro.

Achei essa [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5733008/221800) que dá uma outra solução, mas é bem ruim usar isso.

Outra solução que não é o ideal: pode simplesmente deixar os 10 primeiros elementos vazios. Fazer um cálculo antes de usar o índice. Resolve, mas não transparentemente.

Eu simplesmente evitaria isto. Talvez com uma descrição mais abrangente do problema, a solução deva ser outra.